# Evaluate $\int _0^{2\pi }\frac{\cos (n\theta) }{a+\cos\theta}\,d\theta$ with $a>1$, $n\in \mathbb{N}-\left\{0\right\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Evaluate $$\int _0^{2\pi }\frac{\cos (n\theta) }{a+\cos\theta}\,d\theta,\quad\,a>1$$

I wrote $$f\left(z\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(z^n+z^{-n}\right)}{\frac{iz^2}{2}+aiz+\frac{i}{2}}$$

The discriminant is $\Delta =a^2-1>0$

Poles are $z=-a\pm \sqrt{a^2-1}$ and $z=0$

$z=-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}$ and $z=0$ are within the unit circle.

Applying the residue theorem, we compute: $2i\pi \lim _{z\to -a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}\left(\frac{-\frac{i}{2}\left(z^n+z^{-n}\right)}{\frac{1}{2}\left(z+a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)}\right)$

The first residue is $\pi \frac{\left(-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)^n+\left(-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)^{-n}}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$

Now $2i\pi \lim _{z\to 0}\left(\frac{-\frac{i}{2}\left(z^{n+1}+z^{-n+1}\right)}{\frac{1}{2}\left(z+a-\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)\left(z+a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)}\right)$  $=\lim _{z\to 0}\left(2\pi \left(z^{n+1}+z^{-n+1}\right)\right)\:$

Comment: You have edited the question. What is it now about? Does it mean that you accepted my answer to the previous version of the question?

Comment: Yes, now it's about whether or not my result is correct / can be simplified.

Comment: I have edited my answer in accord with your new question. I also have commented on the correctness of the result.

Comment: I'm confused by that limit, Symbolab says it's $0$? Also may I ask you to clarify some steps that led you to the simplification of the first residue?

Comment: I have added a hint about computing the residue at $z=0$. What concerns the "simplification" I just happened to know that $\operatorname {arccosh} x=\log (x-\sqrt {x^2-1})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To evaluate the integral $$I(a,n)=\int _0^{2\pi }\frac{\cos (n\theta) }{a+\cos\theta}\,d\theta=\operatorname{Re}\int _0^{2\pi }\frac{e^{in\theta} }{a+\cos\theta}\,d\theta,\quad\,a>1,\quad\,n\in\mathbb N $$
it is suggestive to use the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$ so that
$$
I(a,n)=\operatorname{Re}\left[\frac1i\oint\limits_{|z|=1}f(z)dz\right]
=2\pi\operatorname{Re}\left[\sum_{z}^{|z|<1}
\operatorname{Res}(f,z)\right]\tag1,
$$
with
$$
f(z)=\frac{2z^n}{z^2+2az+1}\tag2.
$$
The only pole of $f(z)$ lying inside the circle $|z|=1$ is the simple pole at $z=-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\equiv z_a$.

The residue at the pole can be easily evaluated as
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f,z_a)=\lim_{z\to z_a} (z-z_a)f(z)=\frac{z_a^n}{\sqrt{a^2-1}},
$$
so that finally
$$
I(a,n)=\frac {(\sqrt{a^2-1}-a)^n}{\sqrt {a^2-1}}2\pi\equiv
(-1)^n\frac { e^{-n\operatorname{arccosh} a}}{\sqrt {a^2-1}}2\pi.
$$

Comment: Sure but what does that have to do with the limit when $z$ approaches $0$?

Comment: I just don't understand what the residue in $0$ is, I know it's painfully obvious to you I'm sorry

Comment: The residue of a function $f (z) $ at a point $z_0$ is by definition the coefficient $c_{-1} $ of the Laurent series $f (z)=\sum_{k=-\infty} ^\infty c_k (z-z_0)^k $.

Comment: Ok I knew that much, just where is that coefficient here? I can't clearly see what our Laurent series looks like

Comment: Hi sorry I've been busy with other integrals, are you 100% sure we have to use Laurent series and it can't be computed with the limit?

Comment: Ok still on the residue at $0$, doesn't the first line expand into $z^{n-1}+z^{-1-n}$? What happens in the line where you wrote $k=\frac{n-1}{2}$? And can't $f_0\left(n\right)$ be simplified?

Comment: Ah yes you're right I wasn't treating it as you explained

Comment: @Velyth I now give a much simpler solution with explicit simple expression for the final result. Hope you enjoy it.

Comment: Excellent! Only question is where did $z^{-n}$ go when you wrote $f(z)$?

Comment: @Velyth It is absent and this is the essence of the simplification performed in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

As cosine is an even function, integral from o to 2$\pi$ can be written as 2 times the the integral from 0 to $\pi$, So you would be left with the upper semicircle and hence take $\frac{-ai + i \sqrt{a^2 -1}}{2}$. This is because in the upper plane imaginary part $Im(z) >= 0$.